# Remove from session Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.8

I have a problem in remove the items from session when user click the remove item button from the session. Let me divide my problem in two parts

1. There are certain items in cart, if i click remove item button,
   items are removed from session based on index value sent by ajax
   request. In this case i have not refresh the page that display the
   products.
2. There are certain items in cart, if i click remove item button for
   any product, the product is now removed from session and their are
   remaining products. Now if i refresh web page, their index value
   decreased by one since i already removed one item from session. Now
   if i click remove button, some of the product are not removed. Can
   anybody suggest me what actually happening here.

Thanks

Part of vue code

```
 <div class="card-body" v-for="(list,index) in cart">
     <img :src="list.image" width="80">
     index:{{index}} {{list.name}}
     <button @click="remove(index)">X</button>
  </div>
 remove(index){
     axios.get('/delete',{
         params: {
            index: index,
         }
     }).then((response)=>{
         //this.cart123.push(product)
     });
  }
```

This is the method to remove Item from session

```
public function removeFromSession(Request $request){ 
   $index = $request->index;//index value of item sent from view when user clicks remove item
   $request->session()->forget('product.' . $index);
}
```

Data stored in session as

```
[
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "Marlene Reichert",
    description: "Debitis asperiores sed sit assumenda unde quo natus. Consequatur est labore tenetur quae. Eius distinctio ea omnis aspernatur porro earum quae.",
    category_id: 3,
    price: 76,
    image: "http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=71",
    created_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
    updated_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
    qty: 1
    },
    {
    id: 4,
    name: "Bart Kuvalis",
    description: "Eaque iure excepturi nisi est dolore sapiente in sequi. Minus odit ab et id consectetur sunt.",
    category_id: 9,
    price: 162,
    image: "http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=40",
    created_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
    updated_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
    qty: 1
    },
    {
    id: 6,
    name: "Kaylin Emard",
    description: "Et aperiam omnis nam iure id non fugiat. Excepturi voluptatem ipsam magnam. Esse asperiores ducimus enim et.",
    category_id: 8,
    price: 14,
    image: "http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=17",
    created_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
    updated_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
    qty: 1
    }
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, You didn't used the 
`use Sessions;`
At the top of controller page .

Or try with `Session::flush();`

Comment: Session::flush(); removes all item, i want to remove item one by one based on remove button click